# Нужно сделать так чтобы псевдоэлемент не реагировал на hover, CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, псевдоэлемент

link имеет анимацию появления underline в навигации. При наведении на link, подчеркивание выезжает вверх. Но если курсором успеть навести на эту линию, hover анимация снова срабатывает. Есть ли способ избежать этого и сделать активацию hover только по наведению на ссылку?

```css
body {
  background-color: #e6f0ff
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.header--nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 38px 0;
  column-gap: 64.5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav--list {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: auto;
  column-gap: 30px;
}

.nav--link {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #5a6473;
  line-height: 1.3125;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav--link:visited {
  color: #5a6473;
}

.nav--link::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #5a6473;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.nav--link:hover {
  color: #2d323a;
}

.nav--link:hover::after {
  bottom: -3px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav--link:active {
  color: #717d8f;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav--list">
  <li class="nav--item"><a href="#" class="nav--link">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav--item"><a href="#" class="nav--link">Fratures</a></li>
  <li class="nav--item"><a href="#" class="nav--link">Service</a></li>
  <li class="nav--item"><a href="#" class="nav--link">Listed</a></li>
  <li class="nav--item"><a href="#" class="nav--link">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.nav--link::after { pointer-events: none }`

Comment: большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На тот (псевдо)элемент, который не должен реагировать на мышь:

```
pointer-events: none;
```